# The whole nine yards

Tags: expressions

What is the origin of the term "the whole nine yards"? I have read many explanations, including one that nine yards refers to the length of the belt of wing-mounted machine guns in US fighter aircraft. Thus to "give him the whole nine yards" meant that the pilot fired off a long burst.

Comment: It looks like the theory regarding mounted machine-guns was essentially debunked when the phrase was found to have antedated World War II.  OED has citations from 1855, 1907, and 1908.

Comment: Who upvotes such easily spotted duplicates? Are they trying to make the site look unprofessional?